# Need to hard reset Dlink router once a week

Tags: wireless-networking, router

I am having a [Dlink DIR 655](http://www.dlink.com.sg/products/?idproduct=21) router at the home. Once a week randomly, I see that my connection becomes weak and faulty. I have to go and do a hard-reset of the router (switch off and switch on), so that my wireless connection becomes usable again. Could this problem be with a bad router product or can I do something to have reliable wireless connection through out? If you have faced this problem how have you dealt with?

Comment: I'm not trying to be a troll or anything, but I had to do the exact same thing with my DIR-655 (latest firmware, tweaked settings, etc...).  I was so frustrated that I just replaced the router with one that supported OpenWRT.  I only noticed connection issues over wireless, not over ethernet.

Comment: Which connect becomes weak and fault -- the connection between your machines and your router or the connection between your router and the Internet?

Answer (score 5):

If you've already [updated your firmware](http://www.dlink.com.sg/support/support_detail.asp?idProduct=21) and there was no improvement, you might want to either return it, or, if it's already out of warranty/return period, check the in browser administration page. There should be a button to reset the router. If pressing that button fixes the problem by resetting the router, then you'll have a way to automate it.

I've had sort of a similar problem and the way I solved it way like this: I used developer tools within Firefox (you could also use Wireshark or most other browsers) to check the POST data that is sent when you click it. Once you have that, you can easily replicate this by using cronjobs/scheduled tasks and curl.

I use it on a Windows server to run once a day and basically it looks like this:

```
curl.exe --head -d "POST_DATA_HERE" username:pass@192.168.0.1/apply.cgi
```

Obviously you'll need to find what exactly (if anything) is sent to your router, and if the control panel reset is even sufficient.

Answer (score 4):

Check the ventilation around the router: make sure it is getting enough air circulation to not overheat.  Many network devices operate on the edge of their thermal limits and all it takes is a bit of dust, being covered by papers, or being shoved under a shelf to push them over the edge.

Poor behavior after running for a few days (or even just a few hours), followed by good behavior after a restart is a classic symptom of heat damage.  It is also a symptom of a buggy router, so check the firmware too.  Unfortunately, once the components have been damaged by heat they may not recover even with cooling.  So you might need to replace it anyway.  Just make sure all your network devices are well ventilated.

Comment: That's a helpful response. I should take care of that.

Answer (score 2):

First, update your firmware. If this does not address this, this would not surprise me. DLink is pretty bad for quality assurance of hardware. I've seen unreasonable lack of connectivity and proper functionality from their devices in multiple situations. If this does not get resolved you should consider an Asus or Linksys router. Now adays getting one with built in gigabit switching is really the way to go, it costs a bit more, but gigabit switching is so much better than 10/100, it's like night and day.

Example: http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833320038

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, DLink doesn't have a very good reputation on building high quality products. Nevertheless I have seen cases that NAT in a router is causing memory leaks and performance degradation over time.

Sometimes a firmware update can fix this, sometimes it might be better to buy a different product.

These kind of things are hard to diagnose if you don't have full access to the firmware and/or router, but if you get problems after a lot of traffic using torrent clients (to name a classic example) you might be having that issue. (Torrent clients are making tons of connections to a lot of different ports and therefore consume a lot of router resources.)

Make sure the router isn't overheating, make sure you don't have a neighbor who's transmitting on the same wireless channel as you do (use a program like Insidder to check that.) and with all of this you probably can tell what is causing your specific issue.

Good luck and hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

You might want to look at [www.dd-wrt.com](http://www.dd-wrt.com). This is an open source router OS firmware that can be installed on many different brands of routers. You might look to see if this kind of option is possible, and if you router will support installing it.

Comment: The DIR 655 cannot run dd-wrt because it uses a Ubicom processor.

Comment: Yepper...http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Supported_Devices#D-Link